# spaCy Rules to annotate words based on previous label

Tags: label, spacy, rules

I am building a NER system with spaCy and I want to define some rules. Right now I want the system to determine the gender of names, when before a name stay words like Mr. or Mrs. and if so to basically annotate the names the same as the word before them is annotated.

To give you an example, if I have the following sentence: "Mr. Johnson goes to Los Angeles", my tagger can already classify the word "Mr." as male, but the word "Johnson" is labeled as unknown and not as male. I would like the tagger to look after constructions like this and annotate the second term in the construction the same as the first one. Is this possible, at least?

The code below is not working for me right now.

```
for ent in doc.ents:
if ent.label_ == "Male":
    next_token = doc[ent.end]
    if next_token.text[0].isupper():
        rulerAll.add_patterns([{"label": "Male", "pattern": next_token.text}])
nlp.add_pipe(rulerAll, before="ner")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Custom Tagger

From what I understand from your question, if an entity is labeled as `Male`, i.e. the token `Mr` in your case, then the subsequent token is to be considered as part of the Male token i.e. `Johnson` in your case.

As your tagger is able to detect `Mr.` as `Male`, I am assuming you have a tagger that you have built from scratch, and are not using spaCy's tagger.

Then, this can be done in the following manner:

**Code**

```py
import spacy
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

ruler = EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True)

patterns = [{"label": "MALE_NAME", "pattern": [{"ENT_TYPE": "Male"}, {"TEXT": {"REGEX": "\w+"}} ]},
            {"label": "FEMALE_NAME", "pattern": [{"ENT_TYPE": "Female"}, {"TEXT": {"REGEX": "\w+"}} ]}]
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)

doc = nlp("Mr. Johnson goes to Los Angeles, and Mrs. Smith went to San Francisco.")
print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents if ent.label_ in ['MALE_NAME', 'FEMALE_NAME']])
```

---

**Output**

```
[('Mr. Johnson', 'MALE_NAME'), ('Mrs. Smith', 'FEMALE_NAME')]
```

---

### Using spaCy's inbuilt Tagger (for completeness)

If using spaCy's nlp pipeline, and using spaCy models, it is possible to extract male and female names with prefixes using the `EntityRuler` and `Matcher`.

#### EntityRuler

```py
import spacy
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True)
patterns = [{"label": "MALE_NAME", "pattern": [{"LOWER": {"IN": ["mr", "mr."]}}, {"ENT_TYPE": "PERSON"}]},
            {"label": "FEMALE_NAME", "pattern": [{"LOWER": {"IN": ["mrs", "mrs."]}}, {"ENT_TYPE": "PERSON"}]}]
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)

doc = nlp("Mr. Johnson goes to Los Angeles, and Mrs. Smith went to San Francisco.")
print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents if ent.label_ in ['MALE_NAME', 'FEMALE_NAME']])
```

**Output**

```
[('Mr. Johnson', 'MALE_NAME'), ('Mrs. Smith', 'FEMALE_NAME')]
```

#### Matcher

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

# Create patterns
male_name_pattern = [{"LOWER": {"IN": ["mr", "mr."]}}, {"ENT_TYPE": "PERSON"}]
female_name_pattern = [{"LOWER": {"IN": ["mrs", "mrs."]}}, {"ENT_TYPE": "PERSON"}]

# Add patterns
matcher.add("MALE_NAME", None, male_name_pattern)
matcher.add("FEMALE_NAME", None, female_name_pattern)

doc = nlp("Mr. Johnson goes to Los Angeles, and Mrs. Smith went to San Francisco.")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    # Get string representation of pattern name
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id] 
    # The matched span
    span = doc[start:end]  
    print(span.text, string_id)
```

**Output**

```
Mr. Johnson MALE_NAME
Mrs. Smith FEMALE_NAME
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. Is there also a way to annotate every word separately? So to get the output: [('Mr.',  'MALE_NAME'),('Johnson',  'MALE_NAME'), ('Mrs.', 'FEMALE_NAME'), ('Smith', 'FEMALE_NAME')] ?

Comment: That would not be a task I would try to do in spaCy as it would create unnecessary complexity. You can do that by calling `ent.text.split()` once the entities have been detected by spaCy, and then organizing them however you like.

Comment: Yes, so I built a tagger from scratch for German. I have manually annotated the words in the training dataset and now I started to test it. In the training data I have labeled the words in names separately, so "Mr. Johnson" would be labelled like so: 'Mr.' --> male and 'Johnson' --> male. I managed to write  a rule that can combine them together and overwrite the label :  rulerAll.add_patterns([{"label":"female","pattern":[{"LOWER":"mr."}, {"TEXT":{"REGEX":"(^[A-Z])"}}]}])   but then when I evaluate the system, it gets bad results, because the test data is not annotated the same way.

Comment: I do not have full context into what you are working on. If you could update the original question with more context, then it would help. From my basic understanding on your problem, I would start with spaCy's [german](https://spacy.io/models/de) models. Then, use the EntityRuler to find the name like above. That would yield much better results in my opinion.